# Trouble with VB6 app, bringing a dialog to front and focus on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, com, vb6, activex

I have a small utility app written in Visual Basic 6 that has been happily running on XP clients for many years until recently a client who is using Windows 7 has notified and shown me that the behaviour is different.

When my VB app displays the dialog, it remains hidden until the user clicks on it in the taskbar.

I changed the code so rather than using a ".show vbModal" command, I changed to displaying the form with non-modally, and then added various API calls like BringWindowToFront and SetWindowPos to make it top most AND calling .focus on the form, despite these extra instructions the best result I can achieve is to make the form flash prompting the user to click on it.

No matter what I've tried I cannot make the window display topmost, and with focus, without user intervention.

Note. this is an ActiveX exe project and is being called by a Win16 app through COM.

Has anyone else encountered this behaviour and know of a solution?

Any suggestions/advice appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why the -1 ?  What's unclear with this question?

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that the 16-bit app won't run on 64-bit Windows so you may want to look at updating it very soon.

Comment: However you can still run them within a 32-bit VM.  "XP Mode" is 32-bit XP SP3 I believe.

Comment: Ah, possibly, I've never had to run XP mode. That's not a good enough reason to keep running 16-bit code though :)

Comment: I was assuming that if porting the 16-bit code was an easy solution it would have been done by now.  I don't comsider XP Mode a "solution" just a "make do until" answer.

Comment: There is a possible workaround, see my answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12582544/15639)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applications can't (without lying to Windows) steal focus. The calling app should really call [`AllowSetForegroundWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (if it's available on win16) to allow the COM process to steal the focus, or call [`SetForegroundWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) itself.

See the help for `SetForegroundWindow()` for the conditions on setting focus.

Comment: Yeah I read about that 'AllowSetForegroundWindow()' somewhere else and suspected this may be the cause.  Unfortunately I won't have access to the process ID, as we are just creating the activex object using COM instructions such as DIM obj as Object, SET obj = CREATEOBJECT("x.x")

Comment: I'll try the SetForegroundWindow() approach though and see if that helps.

Comment: You can add a method to get the process ID/window handle in the caller, or just globally unlock it by passing `ASFW_ANY`

Comment: I've created a test case myself using a 32-bit client (another VB6 program).  Everything works just fine on XP or Vista, but the ZOrder problem occurs in Win7 (tested SP1).  Even AllowSetForegroundWindow() made no difference, and I confirmed I was calling it from the ActiveX EXE's process.

Comment: Erm, it needs to be called from the process that already has the focus. It's a bit silly if a random application that doesn't have focus could allow itself to.

Comment: I checked the call's result (and displayed the PIDs of both processes) and it returns True so all's well there.

Comment: You can also try using ZOrder.